# Study X "at depth"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to say that you wish to "study X at depth" (where X is some subject/field).

I thought you could say "study X at depth" similar to how you could say "study X in depth", but I'm not so sure anymore

Comment: If you used *at depth*, I would initially infer that it was an underwater study.

Comment: I do occasionally see "at depth", but I think it mostly occurs in a phrase similar to "When X is examined at depth ..."

Comment: @HotLicks if you can say "when X is examined at depth..." why can you not say "I want to study(/examine) X at depth" ?

Comment: @PixelZerg - You can, it's just not as idiomatic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have (con)fused  "in depth" and "at length" with one another.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-depth) define *in-depth* as:

> done carefully and in great detail

For example:

You might have studied American modernism *in-depth*.

---

The idiom *at length* is defined by [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+length) as:

> in great detail

For example:

I studied American modernism in college, so I can speak about it *at length*.

Comment: What a **reasonable** answer.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely study something "in depth". I wonder if you are thinking of the expression "at length"? 
"I studied the author in depth and then we discussed him at length".

Comment: This is the beginning of a valid answer. Perhaps you can flesh it out with some sourcing and examples of usage.